# Best practice to connect to pnp online in azure runbook

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnpjs, azure-automation

there are so many approaches, can anyone suggest which is best and secured way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Most secure way to do this is with Client ID and Certificate via an Azure AD registered application.

I've [documented the setup process](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2020/12/sharepoint-azure-pnp-provisioning/) end to end for site provisioning which involves PnP provisioning without using a user credential via Azure LogicApps + Azure Automation/Runbooks.